# Не могу зарегистрироваться на Versel. Пишет: Your account requires further verification

Tags: хостинг

Не могу понять в чем причина? Не могу ни с гитхабовского аккаунта, ни с простого имейла зарегистрироваться... Подскажите, умные люди!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я вот не понимаю, почему вот такие люди как вы, думают, что надо писать в какой-то программерский ресурс, вместо того, чтобы написать в поддержку того ресурса, которым решили пользоваться? Вот расскажите свою логику...

Comment: Тем более в надписи даже написано, что надо сделать...

Comment: На любые глупые вопросы надо отвечать...

Comment: Здесь отвечают на вопросы только по тематике сего ресурса.

Comment: Санкции, написано же пиши в поддержку, скажи что не будешь